# Move UIButton within a circular border?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewanimation

In my app I need to move a *uibutton* within a circular border, I tried the following code but it does't seems to be working -

```
- (IBAction) imageMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event{

    UIControl *control = sender;
    UITouch *t = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint pPrev = [t previousLocationInView:control];
    CGPoint p = [t locationInView:control];

    if (control.center.x>40&&control.center.x<300) {
        CGPoint center = control.center;
        center.x += p.x - pPrev.x;
        center.y += p.y - pPrev.y;
        control.center = center;
    }else if (control.center.y>40&&control.center.y<320){
        CGPoint center = control.center;
        center.x += p.x - pPrev.x;
        center.y += p.y - pPrev.y;
        control.center = center;
    }else{

    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try logging the `control` variable and the previous point and current point?

Comment: Yes i did, but after control.center.x reaches 40 uibutton gets struck at that point, more over coding this way restricts uibutton within a square border not a circular.

Answer (score 0):

to move `UIButton` with touch you can not use any touch methods like `touchBegin` or 'touchMoved`.

You have to create IBAction for different actions like

```
UIControlEventTouchDragOutside
UIControlEventTouchDragInside
UIControlEventTouchDragExit
UIControlEventTouchDragEnter
```

by using these methods you can move the button...

AND to keep moving in only circular border your logic looks good....